# No puedo almacenar las variables - PHP

Tags: php

Actualmente estoy trabajando un código donde extraigo el contenido que no necesito de una url cuando es cargada, dejo el contenido que si necesito y luego lo almaceno en una variable, pero lo hace solamente con la primera variable con el resto no lo hace,  cuando mi url no trae el contenido que necesito extraer sino que viene "limpia" todas las variables se almacenan, dejare un ejemplo de una url limpia y la otra que necesito limpiar y almacenarla en la variable. A continuación dejo el codigo:

```html
<?php
ob_start();


header( "Expires: Mon, 20 Dec 1998 01:00:00 GMT" );
header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT" );
header( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header( "Pragma: no-cache" );


include("../directory/file1.php");
include("../directory/file2.php");
include("../directory/file3.php");


header("Content-Type: image/gif");

$fecha = date("Y-m-d");
$hora = date("H:i:s");    
$ip = $_SERVER{'REMOTE_ADDR'};
$navegador =  $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$navegador = stripslashes($navegador);

$ID = ereg_replace("\|", "", $ID);

$adminId = preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST['A'])));
$listaId = preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST['L'])));
$campanaId = preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST['C'])));
$emailId = preg_replace('/^3d/', '', strtolower(stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST['ID']))));
$linksId = preg_replace('/^3d/', '', strtolower(stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST['U']))));
$redirect = preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($redirect)));

echo $adminId;//Solo se llena esta variable
echo $listaId;//De aqui en adelante el resto de las variables estan vacias
echo $campanaId;
echo $emailId;
```

**URL Limpia:** https://www.dominio.com/directory/archivo.php?A=796&L=37803&C=177392&ID=email@gmail.com
Nota: Con esta URL las variables se almacenan sin problemas

**URL con contenido extra:** https://www.dominio.com/directory/archivo.php?A=3D796&L=3D37803&amp=;C=3D177392&ID=3Demail@gmail.com
Nota: Con esta URL solo puedo almacenar la primera variable.

Edición solicitada por la comunidad:

Imprimendo el GET me traje lo siguiente:

Array ( [A] => 3D796 [amp;L] => 3D37803 [amp] => ;C=3D177392 [amp;ID] => 3Dserranol82@gmail.com ) El admin Id es: 796 La lista Id es: La Campana Id es: El Email Id es: El linkId Id es: El redirect Id es:

Comment: Puedes revisar quitando la variable amp, o puedes imprimir todas las variables get para que veas si están llegando y en caso de que estén llegando que no la codificación este correcta. print_r($_GET);

Comment: Con la URL limpia las imprimo sin problemas con un echo, con la URL que trae el contenido extra es que me almacena solamente la primera variable, por logica si almacena la primera deberia almacenar las siguientes. Pero por una extraña razon no lo esta haciendo.

Comment: Nos darías más información si, como te indica @AlbertoOrtega, nos mostraras que te arroja `print_r($_GET) `  en cada caso  (edita la pregunta, no lo coloques aquí)

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo edito

Comment: ok! ¿ves ahora el problema? Solo "almacena la primera" porque es la única que se llama como tu esperabas (el la única que buscas correctamente)

Comment: Por favor podrias colocar la respuesta colocando exactmaente como debe estar el codigo.

Comment: No hay respuesta posible, el problema lo tienes en la URL no en el código. Si quitas el `&amp=;C=`  y lo conviertes en `&C=` ya lo tienes solucionado, quedando:  `https://www.dominio.com/directory/archivo.php?A=3D796&L=3D37803&C=3D177392&ID=3Demail@gmail.com`   ¿Comprendes?

Comment: El problema es que esa URL me la construye los servidores de correos no la construyo yo.

Answer (score 0):

No se si hay alguna función o configuración que te solucione el problema directamente, mientras puedes usar esto para limpiar los datos:

```
<?php
// capturamos los parámetros mediante las variables de servidor; NO VALIDO PARA SCRIPTS DE CONSOLA
$parametros_raw = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// limpiamos las incidencias conocidas
// Si no hace falta str_replace esto usaremos solo html_entity_decode 
$parametros_raw = str_replace('&amp=;', '&', $parametros_raw);
$parametros_raw = html_entity_decode($parametros_raw);

// prepramos la variale para recibir los datos
$parametros = array();
// parseamos el texto y convertimos a valores en el array
parse_str( $parametros_raw, $parametros);     
/*
// verificamos visualmente los datos
echo '<pre>';
print_r($parametros);
echo '</pre>';
*/

$adminId = !empty($parametros['A'])?preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($parametros['A']))):null;
$listaId = !empty($parametros['L'])?preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($parametros['L']))):null;
$campanaId = !empty($parametros['C'])?preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($parametros['C']))):null;
$emailId =!empty($parametros['ID'])? preg_replace('/^3d/', '', strtolower(stripslashes(trim($parametros['ID'])))):null;
$linksId = !empty($parametros['U'])?preg_replace('/^3d/', '', strtolower(stripslashes(trim($parametros['U'])))):null;
$redirect = !empty($parametros)?preg_replace('/^3D/', '', stripslashes(trim($parametros))):null;
?>
```

Tienes más información sobre el parseador en la documentacion oficial de php: http://php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php